# Proton 5.21-GE-1 doesn't work suddenly

Tags: steam, wine

Proton 5.21GE-1 doesn't work suddenly, so i launched steam on terminal to see what's happening.

this is the log i got

https://pastebin.com/gpebk8rW

Launching proton manually on terminal works, at least it starts instead of crashing before starting like it's on the log

I don't have /usr/lib/python3.7 directory, i only have pytnon2, python2.7, python3.8, python3.9 in there

PC information
OS is linux mint with latest kernel
GPU driver is latest i can get for GTX 1050
CPU is i5-6700
24GB of ram

Comment: The log disappeared from pastebin, you could totally paste it in the question directly. Or simply just send us the interesting part.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting steam was the solution, by typing "steam --reset" I should have tried this first